# Xen hangs on boot when scrubbing RAM

Tags: xen, kernel

I have a CentOS 5 server I can boot into the stock kernel just fine, but when I try kernel-xen, it gets stuck here:

[image]

When I try adding no-bootscrub to the kernel command line, I get this and a reboot:

[image]

Does anyone know where I can go from here?

Comment: Which version of CentOS 5 are using? kindly check out following service are onboot is started.

chkconfig network on
chkconfig ntpd on
chkconfig ntpdate on

chkconfig iptables off
chkconfig ip6tables off

Edit "/etc/selinux/config"

SELINUX=disabled

chkconfig --list | grep xen
xenconsoled     0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
xend            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
xendomains      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
xenstored       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
Reboot and try!

Comment: CentOS 5.8. Yes all that is done..

Comment: This looks like you need to exclude a certain memory range. Do your get any hint about that when booting the stock-non-xen-kernel? Please add some details about the hardware of your server.